# Странности с индексированием вершин и интерполяцией цветов в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, графика

Заметил интересную особенность в OpenGL, связанную с индексированием вершин, и пока-что не могу понять почему так происходит.

**Итак, в чем суть:**

Порядок обхода вершин для видимых граней у меня ***по часовой стрелке***. Есть 4 вершины (обычный прямоугольник), заданы они примерно следующим образом:
[image: порядок вершин в массиве]

В массиве они лежат вот так :

```
    vertices[DefaultGeometryType::PLANE] = {
        { { (size / 2), (size / 2), 0.0f },{ 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f },{ 1.0f,1.0f } },
        { { (size / 2), -(size / 2), 0.0f },{ 0.0f,1.0f,0.0f },{ 1.0f,0.0f } },
        { { -(size / 2), -(size / 2), 0.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f } },
        { { -(size / 2), (size / 2),  0.0f },{ 1.0f,1.0f,0.0f },{ 0.0f,1.0f } },
    };
```

Затем у меня есть массив индексов для этого квадрата. Он выглядит так :

```
    indices[DefaultGeometryType::PLANE] = {
        0,1,2,0,2,3
    };
```

Таким образом получается, что квадрат разбивается на 2 треугольника с общими вершинами 0 и 2 (диагональ 0-2 будет общим ребром для этих двух треугольников). В итоге я получаю вот такую картину:

[image: индексы первым способом]

Вроде бы все в порядке. И тут я решил немного поменять индексы, чтобы общим ребром для двух треугольников была диагональ не 0-2 а 3-1. Я изменил индексы следующим образом:

```
3,0,1,1,2,3
```

И в итоге квадрат стал выглядеть вот так:

[image: индексы вторым способом]

Согласитесь, картина совершенно другая. Такое ощущение что интерполяция цветов происходит не совсем корректно. Я пробовал разные варианты порядка индексов, но всегда получалось так, что когда прямоугольник делится по диагонали 0-2 - все хорошо, а когда 3-1 - такая странная картина. Но почему? Может это какое-то неправильное индексирование вершин? Есть ли какие-то правила корректного индексирования? Или же я что-то упускаю и на самом деле так и должно быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Картинки правильные. Просто вы видимо ожидаете получить в итоге gradient-to-gradient gradient, а по факту тут два *отдельных* градиента. Заметьте, что цвет вершины, не принадлежащей данному треугольнику, для вычисления цвета пикселей этого треугольника не используется. Для построения "правильного" градиента пришлось бы сначала рассчитать градиент для каждого пикселя между вершинами 0 - 1 и 2 - 3, а затем рисовать сетку прямоугольников высотой в один пиксель. В более продвинутой форме такое реализуется например в Direct2d:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется понял. То есть это происходит не потому что индексы были заданы как-то некорректно, а просто потому что для вычисления цветов каждого треугольника используются только цвета его вершин, и в разных случаях на треугольники приходятся разные цвета? Но вообще, каких-либо правил, как нужно формировать "корректные меши" (очередность и прочее) - нету? Главное чтобы порядок соответствовал установленному обходу (по/против часовой стрелке)? Или есть какие-то нюансы?

Comment: @AlexNem Порядок важен только если используется culling